# Docker Wkhtmltopdf HostNotFoundError

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf

As I try to run wkhtmltopdf (v 0.12.5) inside a docker container (which works fine if I try to generate a pdf from external url (http://google.de), I'm getting this error:

> wkhtmltopdf http://app.local/web/app_dev.php/get/media media.pdf
>   Loading pages (1/6) Error: Failed to load
>   http://app.local/web/app_dev.php/get/media, with network status code 3
>   and http status code 0 - Host app.local not found Error: Failed
>   loading page http://app.local/web/app_dev.php/get/media (sometimes it
>   will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
>   Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError

I guess the problem is, that the container itself doesn't know about the /etc/hosts entry which I added on my local machine

> 127.0.0.1 app.local

I'm confused and stuck because I don't know how to solve this. I use symfony, but that doesn't really matter, as I get the error above when I use it inside the container itself  by docker exec -it  bash. 
Runnin the script without docker works fine.

Can anyone provide me a solution or a hint how to get this runnin'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add host to containers' `/etc/hosts` using `--add-host`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts).

Something like:

```
$ docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.22     09d03f76bf2c
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
86.75.30.9      db-static
```

Comment: Ok thats a good hint. I forgot to tell you about using docker-compose and a dockerfile. But you gave me the right way so I found https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts which is exactly what I meant to do :)